# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, exception, android-sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

The data access code in my Android app raises an exception.

Here is the code that causes the exception:

```
String getPost = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_POST + ";";
Cursor result = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(getPost, null);
List posts = new ArrayList();{
Log.d("count", result.getCount() + " post rows");
while (result != null && result.moveToNext());
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setPostId(result.getInt(0));
    posts.add(post);
    ....
}
```

The exception raised is:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2 exception
```

The log method produces the result `2 post rows`.

What is wrong here?

Edit: 
I have added the full stack trace so that those wishing to view it can do so.

```
11-14 09:57:50.538: W/dalvikvm(4710): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innolabmm.software.collaboration/com.innolabmm.software.collaboration.PostCommentActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at com.innolabmm.software.collaboration.data.CollaborationDbHandler.fetchAllPost(CollaborationDbHandler.java:362)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at com.innolabmm.software.collaboration.PostCommentActivity.onCreate(PostCommentActivity.java:48)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-14 09:57:50.608: E/AndroidRuntime(4710):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace rather than just the type and message.

Comment: You haven't shown us all the code. Somewhere you are calling `result.getInt(2)` or `result.getString(2)` or otherwise using an index of 2.

Comment: I have added the stack trace but I think the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are attempting to retrieve an item on index 2 but this index really doesn't exist (Cursor size is 2 so indexes are 0,1).

Change your loop:

```
if (result != null && result.moveToFirst()){
    do {
       Post post = new Post();
       post.setPostId(result.getInt(0));
       posts.add(post);
       ....
    } while (result.moveToNext());
}
```

Now it should work correctly.

**Note:** Don't forget to call `moveToFirst()` method that moves Cursor into the first record (implicitly is positioned before the first row) and prepares it for reading. This is also a handy method for testing whether Cursor is valid or not.

**Note 2:** Don't use column indexes, you can simply make a mistake in counting. Instead of use column names - this approach is generally recommended e.q. `cursor.getColumnIndex("<columnName>")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It should improve Android data access code that I write from now on.

Comment: my cursor object was playing up and your solution fixed it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You havent moved cursor index to first .. Try like this below

```
 String getPost = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_POST + ";";
    Cursor result = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(getPost, null);
    List posts = new ArrayList();{
    Log.d("count", result.getCount() + " post rows");

    if (result .moveToFirst()) {
        do {
             Post post = new Post();
             post.setPostId(result.getInt(0));
             posts.add(post);
              ....
        } while (result .moveToNext());
    }
    result .close();
```

Answer (score 3):

This arises in the case our **Cursor** has data but not yet pointing to first index in the data list.

To get avoid this exception, we first should check:

```
if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
        cursor.moveToFirst();
```

And then carry the further actions.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why call cursor.moveToFirst() twice?

Comment: @BrillPappin You are calling that only once. `if (!cursor.moveToFirst())` just checks if it has moved or not. And `cursor.moveToFirst();` is only called if it did not move to first.

Comment: no, you are actually calling it twice. The work done to give you the result is the same. So cursor.moveToFirst() does not change its functionality when inside the IF condition. You don't need the second call, because the first call in the IF block will do all you need (obviously, don't invert the result).

Comment: Try it yourself, write a unit test, and try it both ways.